# Dynamic URL Issue on SEO Scan

Tags: plugins, calendar

I'm getting this URL when I do a SEO scan, how can I remove it and why is this happening

https://thebeginningmontessori.com/?ai1ec_render_js=calendar.js&is_backend=false&is_calendar_page=true&ver=2.6.8

Answer (score 0):

It's not a completely different URL, it's just your homepage URL with some query vars. A plugin probably uses this link somewhere on your website. That would be why this 'SEO scan' picks this up. It sounds like this is more of a problem within your SEO tool than it is a problem within your WordPress installation.